# Restrict user from entering non-numeric value

Tags: python, nameerror, try-except

I am writing a code which should use only def (). input() cannot be used inside def(). When a numeric value is passed, it is okay. When string (e.g. Five, ten, etc.) is provided, it returns NameError. How to fix this issue using try and except.

```
def num(n):
    try:
        return int(n)
    except NameError:
        print('Error: Enter numeric nalue')
        return

num(Five)
```

output: `NameError: name 'Five' is not defined`

I am using Anaconda 2020.2 (Python3.7.6 64-bit)

Comment: You are almost **certainly** not using Python 3.7, where your code would not throw that error, rather, you are using some version of Python 2, where it would. You really should use Python 3

Comment: `num(Five)` this means your are passing variable name `Five`  it shoud look like this `var=input('Enter the input')` `num(var)`

Comment: I have installed Anaconda 2020.2 which shows that it has Python3.7.6 in my installed programs in the control panel. How to check if it is Python2. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @  user13966865 But I am not allowed to use input()

Comment: You’re passing in the variable Five not the string “Five”. If you wanted to test for a user input that is a string you should try / except for a ValueError not a NameError, and run the function as num(“Five”), since the user input would be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. When you are trying to test your routine with a string value, you are trying to code the string constant without the quotes, so that it is instead trying to look up the non-existent variable `Five`, hence the `NameError`.  You need quotes around it (i.e. `'Five'`).
2. Inside your function, the relevant exception to look for in the case of non-numeric data is a `ValueError`.

Example with these corrected:

```
def num(n):
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error: Enter numeric value')
        return

print(num('Five'))
```

Answer (score 0):

below
(the idea is to return a tuple from the function call. first tuple element is a boolean that tells if we have a valid int. second tuple element can be the actual int or a string that explains why we cant convert the input to int)

```
def to_int(val):
    try:
        result = int(val)
        return True,result
    except ValueError:
        return False,'{} is not a valid integer'.format(val)
        
print(to_int(7))
print(to_int('ttt'))
```

output

```
(True, 7)
(False, 'ttt is not a valid integer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def num(n):
   try :
      return int(n)
   except:
      raise NameError("Please provide an integer value")
  
num('five')
```

Comment: are you sure this will work? The code will throw an error. num is a function and you are trying to convert num (a function) into an int.

Comment: To be more specific, `return int(num)` will throw an error.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote num intsead of n. :)